# Assigning generic types to property

Tags: c#, generics

I want my objects to have a reference to the collection that they live in.

I have a collection class deriving from `ObservableCollection<>`:

```
public class MyObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T: class, IMyItem

public interface IMyItem
{
   MyObservableCollection<IMyItem> Owner;
}
```

In it, I have overridden `Insert( )` and `Remove( )`, so that it can assign it self to a property on `IMyItem`, but I'm not allowed to because of

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyObservableCollection<T>' to
'MyObservableCollection<IMyItem>'
```

How can  I get around this problem?
Could/should the problem be solved in a completly different manner?

The code from insert:

```
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
        item.Owner = this;
    }
```

Comment: You've set a type constraint on `IMyItem`, yet the error message mentions `IMoveableItem`. Is that just an error when writing the question?

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you define your interface like that:

```
public interface IMyItem<T> where T : class, IMyItem<T>
{
    MyObservableCollection<T> Owner { get; set; }
}

public class MyItem : IMyItem<MyItem>
{
    public MyObservableCollection<MyItem> Owner { get; set; }
}

public class MyObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : class, IMyItem<T>
{
    protected override void InsertItem ( int index, T item )
    {
        base.InsertItem ( index, item );
        item.Owner = this;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void Main ()
    {
        MyObservableCollection<MyItem> list = new MyObservableCollection<MyItem> ();
        list.Add ( new MyItem () );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to declare a concrete class this way:  
    public class MyItem: IMyItem<MyItem>
      public MyObservableCollection<MyItem> Owner {get;set;}
    end;
It's telling me that `MyItem must be convetable to IMyItem<T> in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic class MyObservableCollection<T>`

Comment: You are right, I forgot to add a <T> on the where constraints of MyObservableCollection. So it works, but my real code is a little more complex, involving multiple sub classes of MyItem. When I need to refer any type of IMyItem<>, I have no way of doing that, because of the type parameter on IMyItem...

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the Item class that implements your interface:

```
class Item : IMyItem
{
    public MyObservableCollection<IMyItem> Owner;
}
```

Now, you're creating a new collection:

```
var myCollection = new MyObservableCollection<Item>();
myCollection.Insert(new Item());
```

Now, in your `Insert()` method, you're doing this assignment:

```
newItem.Owner = this;
```

But your `newItem.Owner` is of type `MyObservableCollection<IMyItem>`, while `this` is of the more specific type `MyObservableCollection<Item>`. What you're running into is a problem of generic [covariance/contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx). `Item` might inherit from `IMyItem`, but `List<Item>` doesn't inherit from `List<IMyItem>`.

Stephan Bauer's answer gives you a workaround to this, by having the `IMyItem` interface have a generic reference to itself, thus skipping the whole covariance issue. A different idea is to use `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `ObservableCollection<T>`, since `IEnumerable` is defined as `<out T>`, meaning it supports covariance during inheritance.

Comment: But one of the reasons that I need a reference to the collection, is that I need to manipulate it, and that I can not do through a IEnumerable.

Comment: In that case, Stephan Bauer's answer will probably be the right one for you.